# Is there anyway to get the class instance given the member variable?

Tags: python

While this might seem like a silly example, it's the simplest way i can think of to explain what im after...let's say i have:

```
class MyClass:
    def __init__(self)  -> None:
        self.table_df = pd.DataFrame()
        self.table_df2 = pd.DataFrame()
```

I can do something like this

```
inst=MyClass()
eval('print(table_df)', inst.__dict__)
```

But what i really want to do is given a pointer/reference to property of an instance, be able to get it's parent instance and do something like this (which of course doesn't work)

```
inst=MyClass()    
table_ref = inst.table_df
eval('print(table_df2)', table_ref.parent.__dict__)
```

Comment: In a nutshell: no.

Comment: If you have `table_df`, then you must already have a reference to `inst`...

Comment: @JohnGordon its passed into a method... the method needs to figure out the 'parent'.

Comment: Can you alter the method to take an additional argument, and just pass in the parent?

Comment: yes that's what im doing now...